# JQuery datatable ajax.reload()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working with ASP.NET core(.NET 5)
The ajax.reload does not want to work for me.

The item gets deleted successfully and I get the toast successful message. But the datatable does not get refreshed.

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
loadDataTable();});
```

Unable to show the whole code for loadDataTable as too much code and unable to submit.
The table is working and data is being loaded.

```
function loadDataTable() {


dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/Admin/Category/GetAll",
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
```

'

```
function Delete(url) {
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover",
    icon: "warning",
    dangerMode: true,
    buttons: true

}).then((willDelete) => {
    if (willDelete) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    toastr.success(data.message);
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                                    }
                else {
                    toastr.error(data.message);
               }
            }
        });
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling with the selector

```
$('#tblData').DataTable().ajax.reload()
```

If you're using an older version, probably this one works

```
$('#tblData').dataTable().api().ajax.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

This what happens when you write code at midnight.

Tried the code above same issue.

Tried every reload.

The issue was the If statement.

```
if (data.success) {
```

It was coming back undefined so was not even trying to reload.

Sorted it and everything working.